# jenkins регулярный запуск

Tags: jenkins

Стоит задача запустить job на jenkins несколько раз в час в заданное время:

```
Monday, July 11, 2016 4:02:00
Monday, July 11, 2016 4:04:00
Monday, July 11, 2016 4:06:00
Monday, July 11, 2016 5:02:00
Monday, July 11, 2016 5:04:00
.....
```

Comment: а в чем вопрос?, как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите запускатьcя каждую 2ю, 4ю и 6ю минуту часа, задайте расписание билду (Build triggers -> Build periodically) следующей cron-маской

```
2,4,6 * * * *
```